# Prove there is a linear combination of vectors in $Z_2$ with at least half non-zero coordinates.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of vectors $V$ in $Z_2^n$, such that each coordinate(i.e. from $1$ to $n$) is one in at least one of them, prove that there is a linear combination of these vectors that has $1$ for at least half of it's coordinates.

This is how I've approached the problem so far: Define matrix $A$ with the vectors of $V$ as it rows. Let $R$ be the echelon-row-reduced matrix of $A$, obviously the rows of $R$ and $A$ span the same space. And given the fact that each coordinate was originally non-zero in at least one of the vectors, we can conclude it is non-zero in at least one of the rows of $R$. Let's call the columns which start a row in $R$ special. If there are at least $\frac{n}{2}$ special columns, then the problem is solved(we combine all rows). Otherwise we have more than $\frac{n}{2}$ special columns distributed in less than $\frac{n}{2}$ rows. But I don't know where to go from here.

I also have an extra question, given $V$ is there way to determine what is the maximum number of non-zero coordinates a linear combination of it's vectors can have?

Comment: I don't think the problem is correct. What if $V=\{e_1\} $, and this is in $\mathbb{Z_2}^{10}$ ?

Comment: @namelessstudent, note the condition that each coordinate is non-zero in at least one of them

Comment: (i.e. the $n$ projections $p_k:\Bbb F_2^n\to \Bbb F_2$, $1\le k\le n$, are surjective, i hat to read twice the "...one in at least one of them..." sentence.)

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood that sentence before. Sorry.

Comment: @dan_fulea , where's $V$ ?

Comment: yes, it was a too quick, not well defined comment. So we have a linear code / subspace $C$ inside $\Bbb  F_2^n$, such that all projections $p_k:\Bbb F_2^n\to\Bbb F_2$ on the corresponding $k$.*th* component, $1\le k\le n$, are surjective. We have to show something about its error correcting capabilities.